# Meteorjs : Does querying on Collection take up memory in merge-box on meteor server?

Tags: meteor

Meteor server needs to keep a copy of data-on-client, to manage "Subscriptions". In subscriptions if something changes in the database, the server sends only appropriate data to client by looking at this local copy in merge-box.

Say, I have a Posts collection as follows:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");
```

If I call queries like Posts.findOne() from client (browser), would the server also cache the results of these queries in merge-box on **server** to track what data is available on the client. Please note that these queries are not called from Publish function. These queries are called from browser.

How would the meteor server behave in the following scenarios:

1. When there is a subscription on Posts collection?
2. When there is no subscription on Posts?

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you clarify it, please?

Comment: @PeppeL-G...I have edited the qs. Is the question clear to you? Thanks.

Comment: Still don't know if I get it, but the server is not aware of what queries (calls to `find` and `findOne`) the clients execute. When a client executes a call to `find` or `findOne`, it will only search through it's local subset of the database (containing only the documents it has received from the server via subscriptions), and never inform the server about it. Does this anwser your question? :P

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. Did not know that the queries never reach the server. So, the only ways to fetch data from db is through the meteor-methods and subscriptions, right?

Answer (score 0):

On the client, `find` and `findOne` only acts on the minimongo on the client. The server is therefore clueless of it. The mergebox pertains only to the publish-subscribe functions you define. Therefore, to answer your questions:

1. When there is a subscription and publication for your Posts collection, the server creates/augments the existing mergebox for the client. This consumes CPU and memory to keep the client and server in sync.
2. When there is no subscription for your Posts collection, the client's Post collection should be empty (barring you adding to it from the client). `find` and `findOne` should return an null cursor or empty object.